# Delete duplicate rows based on an uniqueness constraint of a column in VBA

Tags: vba

Given several rows in excel with columns:

```
row1:   header1 header2 header3
row2:   A1      B1      C1
row3:   A2      B2      C2
row4:   A2      B3      C2
```

How do I delete duplicate rows based on uniqueness constraint for header 1.

I.e. I only want to return the last unique row.

E.g. row3 is deleted and row4 kept

Comment: approximately how big is your data, and how do you decide that row3 should be deleted and not row4?

Comment: I just want the last row to be kept thats the decision. Data somewhere from 1000 to 10000 rows.

Comment: What is the uniqueness constraint you mentioned in column 1?

Comment: Just that I want the unique values in column A.

Comment: Can you reverse the sort order in a way that the top one is kept, if so you can use remove duplicates on the data tab.  But you need to sort it in a manner that the one to keep is the first not the last.

Comment: Can you also confirm the data is sorted like in the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this code, replace the sheet7 with your worksheet;

```
Dim x As String 'place holder for column A data

Dim rc As Long 'row counter

x = Sheet7.Range("A2").Value 'get 1st value 
rc = 3 'initialize with next row

Do While x <> "" 'search until you encounter a blank row
   If x = Sheet7.Range("A" & rc).Value Then
        Sheet7.Range(rc & ":" & rc).Delete
   Else
        x = Sheet7.Range("A" & rc)
        rc = rc + 1
   End If
Loop
```